# DateTime timezone in .NET seems to be wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

I have been having some fun with `DateTime` parsing from strings in .NET MVC, and I have identified some curious behaviour. Look at this test:

```
[Test]
public void DoesItWork()
{
    DateTime theTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime theUTCTime = theTime.ToUniversalTime();
    Assert.IsTrue(theTime==theUTCTime);         
}
```

I'm in the UK right now, and its BST, so I expect the UTC time to be an hour behind the value of `DateTime.Now`. So it is. But when I call `.ToUniversalTime()` on my initial date time, as well as subtracting an hour, the value's Kind property is also updated - from Local to Utc. This is also what I would expect.

But when I come to compare the values of these two `DateTime`variables, the equality operator doesn't take account of the different Kind values, and simply reports they're different values. To me, this seems flat out wrong.

Can anyone elucidate why it works this way?

Comment: Because that's the way it's [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/635d5466(v=vs.110).aspx)? _"The current instance and value are equal if their Ticks property values are equal. Their Kind property values are not considered in the test for equality."_

Comment: Are you asserting the objects are of dateTime? What are you expecting if you compare theTime.Kind? There is a type called TimeZoneInfo that can give you date calculations.

Comment: For info, DateTimeOffset behaves the same way (i.e. two "different" DateTimeOffsets with the same UTC are considered equal), so you aren't any better off there. NUnit allows you to specify WithSameOffset on an IsEqual constraint on DateTimeOffsets to make the comparison include the offset. You can do a WithSameKind for DateTimes as shown in [NUnit issue 196](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/196) (near the end of that page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/5ata5aya(v=vs.110).aspx) and [MSDN2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx) when you compare two DateTime values:

> Remarks
>   To determine the relationship of the current instance to value, the CompareTo method compares the Ticks property of the current instance and value but ignores their Kind property. Before comparing DateTime objects, make sure that the objects represent times in the same time zone. You can do this by comparing the values of their Kind properties.
>
> Remarks
>   The Equality operator determines whether two DateTime values are equal by comparing their number of ticks. Before comparing DateTime objects, make sure that the objects represent times in the same time zone. You can do this by comparing the values of their Kind property.

So it's correct.

Link to [DateTime.Kind Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.datetime.kind(v=vs.110).aspx) and again from the remark:

> The Kind property allows a DateTime value to clearly reflect either Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) or the local time. In contrast, the DateTimeOffset structure can unambiguously reflect any time in any time zone as a single point in time.

**UPDATE**

Regarding your comment. IMHO it is expected behavior. Because usually, you don't need to compare two DateTimes from different time zone. If you need to do this although, you have to use DateTimeOffset [DateTimeOffset Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) which is:

> Remarks
>   The DateTimeOffset structure includes a DateTime value, together with an Offset property that defines the difference between the current DateTimeOffset instance's date and time and Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). Because it exactly defines a date and time relative to UTC, the DateTimeOffset structure does not include a Kind member, as the DateTime structure does. It represents dates and times with values whose UTC ranges from 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 Anno Domini (Common Era), to 11:59:59 P.M., December 31, 9999 A.D. (C.E.).

Comment: Well, yes, I agree that it is documented as you describe. Don't you think that's logically wrong though? If you're going to include a Kind instance property, surely it ought to be part of the comparison - or if not there would be a reason why not.